# google maps on angular ui modal window

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have requirement, that if i click on a link a modal window should be thrown with a google map.

I have been using google map javascript api. For modal, have been using angular-ui bootstrap modal.

When i use ng-init, i am able to show the map but, only for first time. When i click for second time, map is getting grey-ed out. So, i thought, i can throw the map, once modal is loaded completely. But while deriving the node of the map element, i am facing issue.

I am going wrong somewhere. If possible, can anyone please point me in right direction.

```
Modal HTML
<!-- This page shows the modal window when user clicks on any of the route -->
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>                  
    <div class="modal-content" id="mw">
        <div class="modal-header">                  
             <h4 id="jd">Route map for {{routeName}}</h4>   
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                            
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:1000px;height:380px;margin:auto;"></div>           
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div> 
    </div>       
 </body>
 </html>
```

Angular controller logic: controller to call the modal window.

```
var pltcrwapp = angular.module('pilotCrewApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
pltcrwapp.controller("PilotCrewController", [
        '$scope',
        'PCService',
        'alertsManager',
        '$compile',    
        '$uibModal',
        function($scope, PCService, alertsManager, $compile, $uibModal) {

            $scope.hitRoute = function(par) {
                //alert(par);                               
                $scope.routeName = par;
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: '/PilotReport/dialogs/routeDetails.gsp',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                  routeName: function () {                    
                                return $scope.routeName;
                             }
                         }
                });
            }  

}]);
```

Controller for modal window:

```
pltcrwapp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, routeName) {  
      $scope.routeName = routeName;              

      $uibModalInstance.opened.then(function(){
              alert('loaded');
              //var jaf = $("#googleMap").get(0);
              var eff = angular.element($('#googleMap'))
              alert(jaf.nodeName);
              var chicago = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65};
                var indianapolis = {lat: 39.79, lng: -86.14};
                var mapProp = {
                        center:chicago,
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        zoom:7
                };              
                //var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
                var map=new google.maps.Map(eff, mapProp);
      });        

      $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.routeName);
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };      
});

//Since we use ng-app directive, manual initialization is not required.
//angular.bootstrap is for manual initialization
//angular.bootstrap(document, ['pltcrwapp']);
```

Thank a lot..